# Workbook_BeforeClose code triggering 'Save Changes' prompt

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that I want to track some details on so I set up a procedure to record what i care about in a separate file, and then save and close that tracking file without ever bothering the user. It's called from the Workbook_BeforeClose event (and a few other places) as shown below.

```
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call logFormState
End Sub


Sub logFormState()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo FileOpen
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\Finance\Finance\Public\BUDGETS\My Junk\Budget Request Form Status.xlsx"
Dim emptyRow As Long
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Date + Time
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Environ("UserName")
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Name
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Path
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AdminInfo").Range("FormComplete")
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AdminInfo").Range("FormSubmitted")

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
FileOpen:
'record info somewhere else?
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem is, this causes excel to ask the user if they want to save their changes, even if the user didn't change anything. I don't see why this would be making changes anywhere other than my tracking file. I've tried removing the "Application.ScreenUpdating" lines as well as the "ThisWorkbook.Activate" line but it has no effect.

To further complicate things, I've found that if I save, close (which brings up the save changes prompt), cancel the save changes prompt (so the file doesn't actually close), save again, and then close again, it will actually close without the prompt.

Hopefully this all makes sense. If I need to clarify anything, please let me know! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Application.EnableEvents = False

Comment: Application.EnableEvents = False is too heavy handed. I want the prompt to show if the user has made legitimate unsaved changes.

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` will stop the user from being notified.

Comment: You could test like this:
 `If ActiveWorkbook.Saved = False Then  `

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Saved was the ticket! Thanks Guest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Guest's suggestion of testing the ActiveWorkbook.Saved attribute I was able to solve my problem (though the cause is still a mystery). Below is the full code for anyone interested.

```
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If ActiveWorkbook.Saved Then
        Call logFormState
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Else
        Call logFormState
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!